# reverse summary matching

Tags: nlp, pytorch

How can we develop a model to assess the relationship between a summary and a text, enabling it to determine their coherence but in reverse?

Also, how to make an inference

We have list of texts (2000) and their matching summaries (7000)

one to many, can be couple of summaries that can describe part of the text

(( Unrelated; our hidden goal [except from learning] it to check this approach for Java to Smali matching ))

````py
current_model = 'google/flan-t5-large'
max_length = 512  # maximum sequence length
num_epochs = 3
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 4

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, tokenizer, max_length):
        self.df = df
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        row = self.df.iloc[idx]
        text = row['text']
        summary = row['summary']
        
        # Select a random text that does not match the summary
        non_matching_row = self.df[self.df['text'] != text].sample(n=1)
        non_matching_dialogue = non_matching_row['text'].iloc[0]

        inputs = self.tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=self.max_length)
        matching_labels = self.tokenizer(summary, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=self.max_length)

        # Tokenize non-matching text
        non_matching_inputs = self.tokenizer(non_matching_dialogue, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=self.max_length)
        return inputs, matching_labels, non_matching_inputs

# Load pre-trained tokenizer
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(current_model)

# Create training dataset and dataloader
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_df, tokenizer, max_length)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Load pre-trained model
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(current_model)

# Define optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs = batch[0]
        matching_labels = batch[1]
        non_matching_inputs = batch[2]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Train on matching text
        matching_outputs = model(input_ids=inputs['input_ids'][0], attention_mask=inputs['attention_mask'][0], labels=matching_labels['input_ids'][0])
        matching_loss = matching_outputs.loss

        # Train on non-matching text
        non_matching_outputs = model(input_ids=non_matching_inputs['input_ids'][0], attention_mask=non_matching_inputs['attention_mask'][0], labels=non_matching_inputs['input_ids'][0])
        non_matching_loss = non_matching_outputs.loss if non_matching_outputs is not None else torch.tensor(0.0)

        total_loss = matching_loss + non_matching_loss
        total_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Batch {batch_idx}, Matching Loss: {matching_loss.item()}, Non-matching Loss: {non_matching_loss.item()}')

# Save the trained model
model.save_pretrained('flan-t5-large-trained')

# Evaluation on the testing set
test_dataset = CustomDataset(test_df, tokenizer, max_length)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

correct = 0
total = 0

# Iterate over the testing set
for inputs, matching_labels, non_matching_inputs in test_loader:
    matching_outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs['input_ids'][0], attention_mask=inputs['attention_mask'][0], max_length=512, num_beams=1, early_stopping=True)
    matching_generated_summary = tokenizer.decode(matching_outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    
    # Check if the generated summary matches the original summary
    is_matching = matching_generated_summary == tokenizer.decode(matching_labels['input_ids'][0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    
    # Update the counts
    total += 1
    correct += is_matching

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = correct / total * 100
print(f'Testing Accuracy: {accuracy}%')
```
````